# Groovy/Grails : How to sort the list of objects by id

Tags: list, sorting, grails, groovy

PublicTraining Class

```
class PublicTraining{
    static hasMany = [trainingOrder: TrainingOrder]
}
```

and TrainingOrder Class

```
class TrainingOrder {
    Date createdOn

    static mapping = {
        sort id:"asc"
    }
}
```

if i want to get all the orders for training

```
def orders = publicTrainingInstance.trainingOrder.sort()
println orders // [59,58] (id of orders)
```

which does not give sorted orders

Comment: On your PublicTraining domain, it's nice to make it "static hasMany = [trainingOrders: TrainingOrder]"  That way, when you reference it as publicTrainingInstance.trainingOrders.sort{it.id}, you'll clearly see you're working with many trainingOrders, not just one.  Makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Default `sort()` is useful for `Comparable` object. If your class is not a `Comparable`, use:

```
def orders = publicTrainingInstance.trainingOrder.sort { it.id }
```

That code will sort by using passed id.

See docs: [http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort()](http://web.archive.org/web/20131003124544/http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort())