# Grails- how to sort the option in select by name?

Tags: grails, select

How can I sort the options in  by name in the GSP file?

```
<select name="degree" id="degree" class="required" value="${userDegree}" >
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <g:each in="${Degree.list()}" var="degree">
    <g:if test="${degree.name == userDegree}">
    <option value="${degree.name}" selected="selected">${degree.name}</option>
    </g:if>
    </g:each>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can fetch list of `Degree` objects and sort them on your view but **it is not recommended to mix view with db logic.**

---

*Say later you want to filter out the list of invalid degrees, what will you do? Add the logic on the view? That is going to be messy.*

So I suggest you do it like this, get the list of Degrees on your controller (*making this controller call another service to give you the list of degrees is even more good*) and pass them to the UI.

```
degrees = Degree.list(sort:"name", order:"asc")
```

then pass it to the view in the Model map.

Your geach will be like this:

```
<g:each in="${degrees.list()}" var="degree">
```

---

Please visit [this link for recommendations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSXJpS_Y9p0) while coding using grails by **Burt Beckwith** it is very important talk.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you should move to controller the composition of the list, order there, and pass it the way you want it to the view and use it in the view with "from".

For the sorting itself look to [Groovy/Grails : How to sort the list of objects by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263836/groovy-grails-how-to-sort-the-list-of-objects-by-id)

For the inclusion in the select look http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.5/ref/Tags/select.html

Comment: @esauro- there is more simple solution. <g:each in="${Degree.list().sort{it.name}}" var="degree">

Comment: Yes, it's more simple but is not well aligned with MVC layers, because you would be doing in the view things that should be done in a controller (or service)

Answer (score 1):

If you always want degree sorted by name in alphabetical order I recommend that you put this in your domain class mapping:

```
static mapping = {
    ...
    sort        name: "asc"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the list order at the select tag as shown below:

```
<select name="degree" id="degree" class="required" from="{$Degree.list('sort':name, order: 'asc')}" value="${userDegree}" >
...
...
</select>
```